# how to get intellisense of 1 JS in another JS in titanium studio

Tags: intellisense, titanium

Lets say i have following variable in One.js

```
var myENUM {
  FIRST: 1,
  SECOND: 2
};
```

Now, when i am working in Two.js, i need intellisense of myENUM.
I know how to do this in Visual studio, but not in Titanium Studio. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use IntelliJ to to write my titanium code and then Ti Studio to manage running the app on device/simulator.

Ti Studio, to my knowledge, is not that good at intelli-sensing anything except the Ti API.

Webstorm/Intellij has the best javascript support I have every found.

Answer (score 1):

Arron Saunders [tweeted](https://twitter.com/#!/aaronksaunders/status/84641782859710464) a nice [link](http://blog.gstreetmedia.com/2011/04/titanium-developer-and-intellisense/) but I think it only cover built in Titanium Objects?